# Widget usage restriction

Tags: kentico

Is there any way to restrict in which **widget zone** and or **widget zone type** the widget can be used in? I am familiar only with restriction of usage only with user roles or by setting permissions for a specific user.

I've studied the online documentation of Kentico but haven't found any particular information about this topic.

**Not asking for any code, just a pointer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do per zone type. Each widget has a security property (see [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/preparing-widgets-for-users/configuring-permissions-for-widgets)), this is pretty much what you have. Essentially you have zone types restrictions:

- group zones
- editor zones
- user zones
- dashboard zones